# I read an ascii file with bash script and I want to test the value after a certain chain of caracter

Tags: bash, ascii

Here is the ASCII file :
`

```
`! ==========================================================

&input
    NB_PROC             = 4,          !! NUMBER OF PROCESS
    MULTIPROC           = 1,          !! IF WANT TO USE MULTIPROC
    Y_MIN               = 0.98,       !! BOTTOM OF THE BOX
    NY                  = 400,        !! SPATIAL DISCRETIZATION
    HOW_MANY_TO_WRITE   = 200,        !! HOW MANY FLOAT ARE WRITTEN PER ROW
    HOW_MANY_ITE        = 4000,       !! HOW MANY TIME STEP ARE WRITTEN IN TOTAL
    SHOW                = 0,          !! CALL GRAPHICAL ADVANCE
    FILENAME_RO         = 0,          !! ADD RO VALUE TO THE FILENAME
    T_FINAL             = 2.,         !! TIME TO REACH
    WRITE_FLOW_COND     = 0,          !! WRITE OR NOT FLOW DATA
    INI_COND            = 0,          !! CONDITIONS FOR INITIAL STATE
    RETRO_ACTION        = 0,          !! CONDITION FOR RETROACTION OF B
    LOR                 = 1,          !! MHD CODE OR NO
    RUN                 = 1,          !! CONDITION FOR RUN
    RO_EK_COND          = 1,          !! CONDITION ON RO OR EK
    LIN                 = 1,          !! LIN/LOG ARRAY FOR AD NUMBER
    NB_RUN              = 10,          !! NB OF RUN
    RUN_MAX             = 1.3,        !! MAX VALUE OF AD NUMBER
    RUN_MIN             = 0.1,        !! MIN VALUE OF AD NUMBER
    
    R_A                 = 1.35E16,    !! RAYLEIGH NUMBER
    R_O                 = .75,         !! ROSSBY NUMBER
    P_R                 = 1.0E-5,     !! TURBULENT PRANDTL NUMBER
    P_R_EFF             = 5.0E-5,     !! EFFECTIVE VISCOSITY
    P_M                 = 5.0E-2,     !! MAGNETIC PRANDTL NUMBER
    EK                  = 2.0E-8,     !! EKMAN NUMBER
    KX_AD               = 370.,       !! X WAVES NUMBER
    KZ_AD               = 10.,        !! Z WAVES NUMBER (RETROACTION ON WAVES)
    OMEGA_AD            = 3.3E5,      !! WAVES PULSATION
    
    F_J_AD              = 100.,       !! WAVES FLUX
    R_BY_BX             = 1.,         !! RATIO OF MAGNETIC AMPLITUDE : Y OVER X
/
! ==========================================================``
```

I want to be able to read if wether or not the value after the chain 'MULTIPROC' is 0 or 1?

So far I wrote the following bash script to look for the string chain but I don't know how to read the following line.. :

```
    #!/bin/bash

    while read -n13 line 
    do
    if [[ $line = 'MULTIPROC' ]]; then
    echo line
    if
    done < config/input.config
```

The script works just to find the chain but how to read what's next?

Thank you

Everything explained above

Comment: Paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation. Also see [FAQ1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001), Also define `how to read what's next?`

Comment: Are you unable to use any external programs such as Awk? Even just sed would simplify this greatly.

Answer (score 2):

With awk:

```
awk -F'[\t =]+' '$2=="MULTIPROC" && ($0 = +$3)' config/input.config
```

With pure bash:

```
while IFS=$'\t =,' read k v junk; do
    [ "$k" = MULTIPROC ] && echo $v
done <config/input.config
```

Comment: @Brunodu94 see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-read to understand how the `read` command works with the `IFS` variable

Comment: This would match `=== MULTIPROC 1`, but that's _probably_ ok.

Comment: @BoppreH I would guess that would be invalid input  but certainly if lines can wrap `... = 1, MULTIPROC =\n 1,` etc, will break my code

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere between awk and pure bash: use grep.

```bash
$ cat config/input.config | grep -oP '^\s*MULTIPROC\s*=\s*\K[01]'
1

$ echo 'MULTIPROC = 0' | grep -oP '^\s*MULTIPROC\s*=\s*\K[01]'
0
```

Or, if you just want a binary status:

```bash
$ cat input.config | grep -qP '^\s*MULTIPROC\s*=\s*1' && echo 'MULTIPROC is enabled'
MULTIPROC is enabled

$ echo 'MULTIPROC = 0' | grep -qP '^\s*MULTIPROC\s*=\s*1' && echo 'MULTIPROC is enabled'
*nothing*
```

Comment: I'm aware of the useless use of cat, but in this case it's better to contrast with the `echo` version.

Comment: @jhnc Thanks for the tips, I didn't know about `\K`.